# Mediastreamer2 Videostream outputwindow in Qt GUI

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, video-streaming, linphone

I'm using Mediastreamer2 to make multiple Videostreams in Qt.
When I start the videostream, mediastreamer2 shows the stream in a new opened window. 
I need the stream in my Qt GUI. Any advise how to solve this?

`video_stream_set_native_window_id(stream,ui->ANYTHING->winId());`

This line changes the windowsID of the Stream, bevor I start it. When it's started, the stream window has a new ID.
Until now, I tried everything in the GUI from widgets to frames...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to have a really hard time having a 3party lib draw onto widgets created by qt and don't think you should try this at all. Even if you manage to hack it in, next qt patch might destroy it all again.

You should try to stream to a buffer instead of directly to the screen. I don't know your stream library but I'd expect this is possible.

Then search the most performance-friendly way to convert this buffer to a QImage or QPixmap and add it to a QLabel. I would expect it to be possible to get this done without having to move any data.
Alternatively, override the paint() method of QWidget and try to get the QPainter to draw your buffer. I don't know if this is possible tho.

Answer (score 0):

I'm realy mad at myself, it is so easy.

`QWindow *wi = Window::fromWinId(video_stream_get_native_window_id(video));
 QWidget *ww = QWidget::createWindowContainer(wi);`

Create a QWindow with the windowID from the mediastream and create a QWidget using a WindowContainer.